# Map columns from parent table directly onto child entity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, mapping

In a one-to-many parent child table relationship, can I map the columns of the parent table directly on to properties child entity (ie without a navigation property)?  For example, with the following two tables:

```
TABLE Foo
    FooId int PK
    FooName nvarchar(max)
    BarId int FK

TABLE Bar
    BarId int PK
    BarName nvarchar(max)
```

Could I create an entity for `Foo` defined like this?

```
Public Class Foo
    Public Property FooId As Integer

    Public Property FooName As String
    Public Property BarName As String
End Class
```

It seems like a job for entity splitting, but entity splitting is only for cases where the two tables have the same primary key (one-to-one), not one-to-many.

Comment: No. AutoMapper could do this for you.

Comment: @GertArnold AutoMapper can map the domain entity to a dto.  AFAIK, it cannot eliminate the navigation property on my domain entity.